# Sorting arraylist of objects based on the date time

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have two arraylists that consist of the datetime objects and merging both the list using.

```
list1.addAll(list2);
```

I want to now sort this arraylist on the order of the date time object that the arraylist consists of. Can anyone guide me how to sort this arraylist.

Comment: @naveen -- it's tagged with java

Comment: `Collections.sort(list1);` should do the trick for you.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you meant they have Java [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object. You can just do [Collections#sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 5):

```
ArrayList<Date> myDates = new ArrayList<>();
// populate the List... 
Collections.sort(myDates);
```

If you are using `Joda Time` Date time, this is done the same way, since those classes usually implement `Comparable`.

Comment: No need for a custom comparator.

Comment: _Almost_ the same?  What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your comparator for the objects of the arraylist, like if I am using objects having structure

and then you can use, sort method directly.