# Best efficient way to sort Months and Year in Java

Tags: java, datetime

I have a list which contains dates in format (MON-YYYY) in string format, I need to sort this list.The approach I have followed till now is reading the list and converting the string in date format and using compare option, but i am not getting the desired result

**Code Snippet**

```
List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Date> xyz = new ArrayList<Date>();

        abc.add("JAN-2010");
        abc.add("JAN-2011");
        abc.add("APR-2013");
        abc.add("NOV-2009");

        try {

            for (String abc1 : abc) {

                Date date;

                date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                        .parse(abc1);
                xyz.add(date);

            }

            Collections.sort(xyz, new Comparator<Date>() {

                public int compare(Date arg0, Date arg1) {
                    // return arg0.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
                    return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
                }
            });

            for (Date date1 : xyz) {
                System.out.println("Sorted : " + date1);
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
    Sorted : Sun Nov 01 00:00:00 IST 2009
Sorted : Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2010
Sorted : Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2011
Sorted : Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

**Expected Output**

```
NOV-2009
JAN-2010
JAN-2011
APR-2013
```

I am also not sure if the above code is perfect in performance perspective as converting the string and parsing would take a long time if I have thousands of dates in MON-YYYY format in the list.

Comment: You are comparing `arg0` to `arg0` which is obviously wrong

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108719/sorting-arraylist-of-objects-based-on-the-date-time on how to sort a collection of dates.

Comment: No need of comparator. Dates are comparable

Comment: Darijan, I have updated it...it was a typo error

Comment: @SJagdeesh please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I see you corrected the typo.

Now, remember you need to use a `DateFormatter` also when you present the data, in addition to when you parse it.

So please try this:

```
        for (Date date1 : xyz) {
            System.out.println("Sorted : " + new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date1));
        }
```

You might want to make the `SimpleDateFormat` available to all methods of your class as a field.

Additional info: please be aware `SimpleDateFormat` is known to not be thread-safe. You can use `ThreadLocal` as one solution to that.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You've parsed your `dateString` to actual `Date` object. And `java.util.Date` can't be formatted. Only a `String` representation of that `Date` object can be got.

You need to change your comparator to compare your `dateString` format by internally converting the Strings to date.

If you are gonna sort the `Date` objects, you'll get the output you've got. Also, as mentioned by **@darijan**, change your logic in the comparator.

Answer (score 0):

First i think it's better to have only one instance of `SimpleDateFormat` and always use this to parse your dates.
I also suggest to create this instance of `SimpleDateFormat` in front of your `try` block, so you solve your second problem and can use `SimpleDateFormat.format(date)` to parse your dates back to requested stringformat.