# how to find biggest and smallest date in a list?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have collection of object as `Collection basics = periodic.getGeneratedBasic();`
When iterate over this collection and get every object and cast it, i can extract date of every object.
Now at this point i want to check out in this collection of object which one is the smallness and biggest date.

**Does any one know how to do that?**

```
Date max;
Date min;
for(Object o:basics){
      Basic b = (Basic) o;
      Date temp;
      if(b.State=='U'){
           basicAList.add(ba);
           dateCollection.add(b.firstDateTime);
           temp= ;
           if(b.firstDateTime <)
     }
  }
```

Comment: @itro, accept an answer which solved your problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) and then take the first/last entries? You can either use *natural* ordering, or specify your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Note this will sort the collection *in-place*. It won't give you a new sorted collection.

Comment: Implemented your idea, but with the auto-sort feature of `SortedSet`, like this: `SortedSet<Date> set = new TreeSet<Date>();`. By the time it runs `set.add( b.firstDateTime );`, it's already sorted, so I could call `Date min = set.first()` and `Date max = set.last()`.

Comment: Sort-on-add is usually faster than sorting the whole list, and using a `Set` prevents duplicate entries...

Comment: Sorry, I meant `set.add( object.getDate() )`

Answer (score 21):

In Java 8 you can do:

```
final Date maxDate = dates.stream()
    .max(Date::compareTo)
    .get();
```

Answer (score 13):

this is a classic **minimum & maximum** problem. no matter your Object is Date or String, or Number. Important is that they are comparable.

**Sorting then take max/min**

Most straightforward method is like others' answer, Sort the collection with  java build-in Sort method. then take the 1st and last element as your min/max object. However it turns a linear time `O(n)` problem into `O(nlgn)` . well if performance matter is not what you  are considering about. you can skip reading my rest text. And I will upvote @Quoi's answer.

**the easy way with linear time:**

keep two variable min and max, then go for each element in your collection. compare to your current min and max and get the right value. till the end.

**the Optimized way with linear time**

the way above is easy, but it brings more comparisons `(2n)`.  we can optimize it a little. Same as above, you have min and max two vars. and in loop, you take a pair of elements instead of single. you compare first the two element in the pair. take the bigger one to compare to your max var, and the smaller one to your min var. now we just have to do `3(n/2)` comparisons.

hope it helps

**Edit**

I think the codes are not so hard to write. As Quoi suggested, if codes could make the answer complete, I would add them.

Note that in the example I used an int array. Basically it is the same as Date object. The codes are written in a unit test method. And it looks long, since I try to explain the idea above clear.

```
@Test
    public void testx() {
        final int size = 300000;
        final int[] array = new int[size];
        final Random random = new Random();
        // fill a huge array for testing
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt();
        }

        int min1 = array[0], max1 = array[1], cmp1 = 0;
        int min2 = array[0], max2 = array[1], cmp2 = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
            min1 = array[i] < min1 ? array[i] : min1;
            cmp1++;
            max1 = array[i] > max1 ? array[i] : max1;
            cmp1++;
        }

        LOG.debug("linear time to find Max & Min simultaneously");
        LOG.debug("Size: {}", size);
        LOG.debug("Max : {}", max1);
        LOG.debug("Min : {}", min1);
        LOG.debug("Total comparisons : {}", cmp1);

        // optimized linear
        int bigger, smaller;
        final boolean odd = array.length % 2 == 1;
        final int till = odd ? array.length - 1 : array.length;
        for (int i = 2; i < till; i += 2) {

            if (array[i] >= array[i + 1]) {
                bigger = array[i];
                smaller = array[i + 1];
            } else {
                bigger = array[i + 1];
                smaller = array[i];
            }
            cmp2++;
            min2 = smaller < min2 ? smaller : min2;
            cmp2++;
            max2 = bigger > max2 ? bigger : max2;
            cmp2++;
        }
        if (odd) {
            min2 = array[size - 1] < min2 ? array[size - 1] : min2;
            max2 = array[size - 1] > max2 ? array[size - 1] : max2;
        }
        LOG.debug("====================================================");
        LOG.debug("optimized linear time to find Max & Min simultaneously");
        LOG.debug("Size: {}", size);
        LOG.debug("Max : {}", max2);
        LOG.debug("Min : {}", min2);
        LOG.debug("Total comparisons : {}", cmp2);
    }
```

output

```
DEBUG:  linear time to find Max & Min simultaneously
DEBUG:  Size: 300000
DEBUG:  Max : 2147475519
DEBUG:  Min : -2147446732
DEBUG:  Total comparisons : 599996
DEBUG:  ====================================================
DEBUG:  optimized linear time to find Max & Min simultaneously
DEBUG:  Size: 300000
DEBUG:  Max : 2147475519
DEBUG:  Min : -2147446732
DEBUG:  Total comparisons : 449997
```

Comment: +1 Good solution. Please add snippet to make this answer complete.

Comment: Perfect explanation.

Answer (score 7):

[`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is `Comparable`, so you can compare two `Date`s using [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29):

```
dateOne.compareTo(dateTwo);
```

> **Returns**:
>   the value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.

You can also sort the whole `Collection` with [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) (O(n logn)):

```
Collections.sort(dateCollection);
```

Or get the maximum with [`Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) and the minimum with [`Collections.min()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29) (both in linear time O(n)).

Answer (score 3):

```
Date max = new Date(0);
Date min = new Date(0);
for(Object o:basics){
    Basic b = (Basic) o;
    if(b.State=='U'){
        basicAList.add(ba);
        dateCollection.add(b.firstDateTime);
        if(min.compareTo(b.firstDateTime) > 0) min = b.firstDateTime;
        else if(max.compareTo(b.firstDateTime) < 0) max = b.firstDateTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp= ;` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @Baz, removed that variable...it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your collection on basis of date and get it. In case ascending order you will get smallest date first and biggest date last and if you sort in descending then you get biggest date at top and smallest date at last.

Comment: What you would suggest as a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date) previous SO post. You could sort your objects by date and then select the first and last items in the collection.