# Android: How to sort list items according to dates

Tags: android

I have a listview with many list items with date in it. I want to sort the items through dates like the items whose dates are after the current date should be first and items whose dates has expired should be after that. can anyone help.

Comment: You can implement this in many ways. What have you tried? Post code, please.

Comment: Great answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date

Comment: There are many threads exist on Stackoverflow itself. Better you try yourself first. Let us know then if you are facing any issue.

Answer (score 13):

You can use your own comparator like that

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<YourObjectInYourList>() {
  public int compare(YourObjectInYourList o1, YourObjectInYourList o2) {
      if (o1.getDate() == null || o2.getDate() == null)
        return 0;
      return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
  }
});
```

Comment: where should i put the above code?

Comment: Put it in anywhere you want to sort your list.

Comment: For example you can sort your list with that way and than put your list to your listView adapter.

Comment: sorry very late, but when you don't have a date then you add an item that has a date, it crashes the app. Any way to work around this?

Comment: i used date cuz item in question has date but if your item has not then you can not use this piece of code. However if you want to sort a list important point is how list should be sorted such as by name, by date maybe by size. You should decide it firstly.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();        
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.US);    
try {
    dateList.add(sdf.parse("01/12/2013"));
    dateList.add(sdf.parse("02/11/2013"));
    dateList.add(sdf.parse("03/12/2013"));
    dateList.add(sdf.parse("04/10/2013"));
    dateList.add(sdf.parse("05/12/2013"));
    dateList.add(sdf.parse("06/12/2013"));      
    dateList.add(new Date());

    Collections.sort(dateList); 
    Comparator<Date> cmp = new Comparator<Date>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
        if(o1.getTime() > o2.getTime()) return 1;
        else if(o1.getTime() < o2.getTime()) return -1;
        else return 0;
      }             
    };

    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();
    List<Date>  out_of_date_list = new ArrayList<Date>();
    for(Date date : dateList){
        System.out.println(">>> date = "+sdf.format(date));
        System.out.println(">>> out of date "+cmp.compare(new Date(), date));
            if(cmp.compare(date,new Date())<0){
                out_of_date_list.add(date);
            }           
    }
    System.out.println(">>> print all out of date ");           
    for(Date date : out_of_date_list){
       System.out.println(">>> date = "+sdf.format(date));      
    }               
} catch (ParseException e) {// TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace();        
}
```