# Android - java - how to sort a list of object byan GregorianCalendar argument

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, calendar

I want to display a List of objects sorted by a date argument in crescent order.
I have tried many ways. But it doesn't work. It's not changing the order of the objects in the list. 
I visited this for help: 
[Android: How to sort list items according to dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560635/android-how-to-sort-list-items-according-to-dates)

[How to Sort Date in descending order From Arraylist Date in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120316/how-to-sort-date-in-descending-order-from-arraylist-date-in-android)

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-sort-an-ArrayList-of-objects-by-each-objects-integer-parameter

Here is my code:

my Class Object

```
public class Evento extends GregorianCalendar {

public Calendar date;
public String tipo = " ";
public String a = " ";
public String b = " ";
public String c = " ";
```

And my MainActivity:

```
public void implementList (View view){

    List <Evento> listEventosAll = new ArrayList<>();

    listEventosAll.addAll(listEventos1);

    listEventosAll.addAll(listEventos2);

    Collections.sort(listEventosAll,  new Comparator<Evento> (){
         public int compare(Evento evento1, Evento evento2) {
             if (evento1.date.getTime() == null || evento2.date.getTime() == null)
                 return 0;
             return evento1.date.getTime().compareTo(evento2.date.getTime());
        }

   }); 


    EventoAdapter adapter = new EventoAdapter(this,listEventosAll);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

populating  ListEventos1

```
public static Evento setEvento(Calendar day, String a, String b) {

Evento evento = new Evento();
evento.date = day;
evento.a = a;
evento.b = b; 
return evento;
```

}

// Creating the list:

public static ArrayList listEventos1(int year){

```
Calendar day = calculateCertainTuesday(year);

ArrayList <Evento> list = new ArrayList<Evento>();

list.add(setEvento(day, "Certain Tuesday”, "do this"));

day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); 

list.add(setEvento(day, "Certain Wendsday”, "do that"));

day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-2); 

list.add(setEvento(day, "Certain Monday", "do what"));


day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1); 

list.add(setEvento(day, "SUNDAY", "don’t do"));


return list;
```

}

Comment: In what order? crescent? As in The Crescent Order is an organization located in Japan that protects the Lotus, an elixir that counters the effects of the Lazarus Pit?

Comment: Are you sure you populate the Evento.date? Because it is your custom field, not inherited from `GregorianCalendar` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** I completly overhauled my answer in response to the new edit on your question.

The problem is that for each `Evento` that populates your `listEventos1`, you're using the same `Calendar` (variable name `day`). You're doing this:

```
list.add(setEvento(day, "Certain Tuesday”, "do this"));
```

And then this:

```
day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); 
list.add(setEvento(day, "Certain Wendsday”, "do that"));
```

But what the call to [`Calendar#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int-) does is it

> Adds or subtracts the specified amount of time to the given calendar
>   field, based on the calendar's rules.

In other words, `Calendar` is a *mutable* class, i.e. it can change states, unlike a `String`, which is *immutable* and will always be the same. Don't worry, you're not the first to make that mistake, and that's [partly why Java introduced a new Date API](https://jaxenter.com/the-new-java-8-date-and-time-api-an-interview-with-stephen-colebourne-107663.html) (more precisely, it's because that made the classes not thread-safe).

So in other words, whenever you're calling the `Calendar#add` method, *all* objects in `listEventos1` change, because they all contain the same instance of `Calendar`. For a really good example of why this happens, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901960/7096763).

One way to verify this is to add a supplementary check in your `Comparator` by using the `==` operator. `==` will return true if the two variables point to the *same* instance:

```
Collections.sort(listEventosAll,  new Comparator<Evento> (){
    public int compare(Evento evento1, Evento evento2) {
        if(evento1.date.getTime() == evento2.date.getTime()) 
            System.out.println("Warning! Two references pointing to the same object!");
         if (evento1.date.getTime() == null || evento2.date.getTime() == null)
             return 0;
         return evento1.date.getTime().compareTo(evento2.date.getTime());
    }
```

Running this with your current code should output a bunch of warnings.

Another tidbit of information: according to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) of `Comparator`, `Comparator#compare` should throw a `NullPointerException` if one of the arguments is `null`.

---

**SOLUTION**
To fix this problem, you need to pass different instances of `Calendar` at each call of `setEvento`. Some classes, such as those in the Collection API possess *copy constructors*, that is, constructors that will take an object as an argument, and return a *new* object with exactly the same values. `Calendar` doesn't implement copy constructors, but it does however implement the `Cloneable` interface, which means you can clone its objects.

Cloning is sometimes [frowned upon](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) in the Java world, but in this specific case [it's a viable option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16679077/7096763).

So here's how to clone `day` so that each time you call `Evento`, it points to a new object (this is your `listEventos1` method):

```
list.add(setEvento(day, "Certain Tuesday", " do this "));
day = (Calendar) day.clone(); //This is what I added
day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Naturally, repeat this for every object your insert.

---

*NOTE:* btw, some quotation marks in your code are closing English quotation marks (`”`) instead of double quotes (`"`). This will break your code.

*OTHER NOTE:* You're not using the inheritance mechanism correctly, and your code could be simplified by using `Evento` as a `Calendar` itself. But that's for another day.

Comment: You mean that I shouldn't have used the argument 'date'? But how do I atribute a GregorianCalendar value to my object Evento?@MikaelF  I changed this : {public static Evento setEvento(Calendar day, String a, String b) {

    Evento evento = new Evento();
    evento.date = day;
    evento.a = a;
    evento.b = b; 
    return evento;

}
For this:

Comment: @Ulla use Envento exactly the way you would use a GregorianCalendar. That's the whole point of polymorphism (and inheritance).

Comment: I changed this : evento.date = day;                  for this : evento.set(day.YEAR, day.MONTH, day.DAY_OF_MONTH);  but its still not doing the sort. how is the best way to populate Evento?

Comment: I"m new in coding and get little lost in this polymorphism sometimes

Comment: Your Evento *is* a GregorianCalendar. That's what *extends* means. This is also why you can directly compare two instances of Evento. Look up polymorphism online (youtube is good for that), you might just be missing a few notions.

Comment: Well I tried whithout extending my Evento object, and it did work for listEventos2 but not for listEventos1 I'm sure missing something when populating listEventos1, I have tried many ways but don't get a clue. I will edit my question to post it.

Comment: Now it makes sense... Sorry that I took so long time to see it and answer ...  Coding is like a hobby for me... and I was little busy with other things.