# Sorting a Json object array list in an expandable list view

Tags: android, json, expandablelistview

I am using  a Json object array list for displaying data. Now I want to use an expandable listview in which the data is classified according to date in the object. how to classify the child list according to the date.

The json object consists of a pick up date and passenger details. I want to sort and make an expandable list view consisting of date in the main list and passenger details in the sub-list sorted according to the date.

Some objects have the same booking date, so they need to be clubbed under one.

This is the json object:

Comment: where are you getting json object?

Comment: Quick question : what have you tried? Please post some code.

Comment: You just need to use Comparator to sort your ArrayList. If you need example, please post some code and json string which you have

Comment: i ll post the json code. how can we sort using date ?? i want to create a new array list of objects coming under same date from the existing arraylist. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you are asking, but if you are trying to sort an array of JSON objects of the following form: `[{},{},..,{}]` then you can use the `Array.sort` method build into JavaScript, and just pass in a compare function that describes how to sort the objects by date.

For example:

Say you have an object like this:

```
var people = [
{
  "name": John,
  "birthday": new Date(1990, 8, 10);
},
{
  "name": Mark,
  "birthday": new Date(1991, 10, 17);
},
{
  "name": David,
  "birthday": new Date(1991, 7, 26);
}
];
```

Now to sort this array you can simply do the following:

```
people.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.birthday - b.birthday;
});
```

Now the `people` array will be sorted by date.

For more information see this [Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: sorry for the question not being clear. actually am accessing A j son object and storing it in an array list. it consist of pick up date and passenger details. i want to sort and make an expandable list view consisting of date in the mainlist and passenger details in the sublist sorted according to the date . now cud you help ??

Comment: am on android platfrom

Comment: If you are use a webview in the Android SDK, you should be able to just use JavaScript to do what you want, which would probably be better since you are using JSON objects.  Either way I'll add another answer that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with the Android SDK, but if you just need to sort an ArrayList that contains JSON objects by their date, I can help you with that part.

I would have your objects in the ArrayList parse your JSON using this [tutorial](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/), and
then with the parsed date create a Date field in your object, and then have the object implement the Comparable interface as described in this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date).  Then you can use `Collections.sort(<list>)` to sort the list.