# Collections.sort isn't sorting

Tags: java, sorting, jakarta-ee, collections

I am building a web application using Java EE (although my problem is more Java based)

In a Servlet, I am getting a list of orders from the EJB. In this list of orders, there is a list of states for this order (sent, on dock, non received ...)

I want to sort this list of states by the date of the state. So I use Collections.sort like this:

```html
    for (Command c : commands) {
        c.getStateList().sort(new Comparator<State>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(State o1, State o2) {
                    return o1.getStateDate().compareTo(o2.getStateDate());
                }
        });

        c.getStateList().sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
    }
request.setAttribute("commands", commands);
```

But when I display the results, the states are not sorted.

I tried to reverse the order as you can see, but it isn't working either.

As you can also see, I replaced the Collections.sort with the ListIWantToSort.sort. Still not working.

Any ideas on why it does not work or how I could repair it?

**EDIT** : Here is the getter for the list and its instanciation :

```java
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ciiCommande")
    private List<Etat> etatList;

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Etat> getEtatList() {
        return etatList;
    }

    List<Commande> commandes = new ArrayList<Commande>();
```

And I get my commands by a findAll Method.

To display them, I use that :

```java
<c:forEach items="${commandes}" var="cmd">
    <td>${cmd.etatList[0].codeStatut.libelleSituation}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: What does `c.getEtatList()` return?

Comment: @LutzHorn it does return the states list taken by the order.

Comment: Does whatever is in `getEtatList()` implement the `Comparable` interface?

Comment: @trichetriche And what exacly is the *type* of this list?

Comment: Can you try to create [a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Is `getEtatList()` returning a copy of the list inside `c`?  If so, you are sorting the copy, which this then promptly discarded, and when you come to output/use `getEtatList()` again you get another, unsorted copy.

Comment: @npinti Using a thread on this website, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date) I didn't implemented the Comparable interface

Comment: @LutzHorn this is a Etat List, Etat is a table in my database, which is an Entity class in my application

Comment: @Paul How do I know if this is a copy of the list ? I am learning Java EE and Java actually

Comment: @assylias it is Rather complicated to recreate an exemple, but if you want to try it, do a custom object, having a list of another custom object property, which have a date property. Then try to sort the list property

Comment: @trichetriche I don't know it is a copy.  It also don't know it *isn't*.

Comment: @trichetriche the problem is that your example works as expected, so the problem is not in the description you have given so far.

Comment: @assylias well my example does work, it compiles fine. The problem is that, it doesn't sort the List how it should do.

Comment: @trichetriche see my answer - I'm doing exactly what your code is doing and the list gets sorted - the problem is somewhere else hence my comment above: try to recreate the issue with a minimal, complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: are you sure your compareTo method works fine?

Comment: @user902383 I don't know, it's a compareTo I get from the Date type, it should work fine, don't it ?

Comment: @trichetriche If I were you, I would add some logging in (1) the method where you sort and (2) the getter and see what the list looks like at each point. It is possible that jsf calls the getter more than once and the returned list is "refetched" and not sorted.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want to sort the commands, or the etatList? Plus, I see you are using Hibernate / JPA. is it possible the persistence framework is interfering with the ordering? And what does @XmlTransient do?

Comment: I want to sort the etatList of each order, not sort the orders. Well, I don't think so, because I get the orders, then try to sort it, and I don't use the PU again. I don't know what @XmlTransient do, NetBeans put it (I used the GUI to create my entity classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of struggle, I managed to find a solution.

The list isn't sorted after every attempt I made. I still don't know why.

But I found an annotation, @OrderBy, that sorts the list the way I want.

Thank you all for your help, maybe one day this problem will be sorted out (see the pun ? I am so funny).

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for (Commande c : commandes) {
                c.getEtatList().sort(Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<Etat>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Etat o1, Etat o2) {
                        return o1.getDateEtat().compareTo(o2.getDateEtat());
                    }
                }));
            }
```

Since the sort method your using has been added to the List interface in Java SE 8, I guess you're using Java SE 8. Then you can rewrite it to the following:

```
commandes.foreach(c -> 
  c.getEtatList().sort(Comparator.comparing(Etat::getDateEtat).reversed());
);
```

Comment: There is no error, everything compiles fine. But in my application, instead of showing "Delivered" (which is supposed to be the last state), it shows "Not Delivered" (which is the previous one). FYI, I am getting the first result of the list to show this state.

Comment: there was some parenthesis errors in your second solution, but even after correcting it, it didn't work either.

Comment: @trichetriche what is the type of dateEtat and what are the possible values?

Comment: dateEtat is a Date, it can take all possibles values accorded to that type. But in my database, it goes from 01.05.2015 to 31.05.2015

Comment: And what is the value of dateEtat in the case of "Not Delivered"?

Comment: its value is the moment when we knew the order wasn't delivered.

Answer (score 2):

You are first sorting the list using the custom comparator.  Then you are re-sorting it according to the reversed *natural* ordering of the elements - not the custom ordering you already applied.  So the first sort is not taking effect as the list is re-ordered by the second sort.  Note that `Collections.reverseOrder()` does *not* reverse the list - it is the reverse of the *natural* ordering (so the elements in `getEtatList()` must already be `Comparable`).

Try losing the second sort and doing:

```
c.getEtatList().sort(new Comparator<Etat>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Etat o1, Etat o2) {
        // Note o2/o1 reversed.
        return o2.getDateEtat().compareTo(o1.getDateEtat());
    }
});
```

Comment: the reverseOrder is actually another try, I didn't used it first. But But thank you for that piece of information, I'll remember that

Comment: What is returned by getDateEtat()?  Is it a `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you need:

```
    Comparator<Etat> comparator = new Comparator<Etat>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Etat o1, Etat o2) {
            return o1.getDateEtat().compareTo(o2.getDateEtat());
        }
    };

    for (Commande c : commandes) {
        Collections.sort(c.getEtatList(), comparator);
        // or this one: Collections.sort(c.getEtatList(), Collections.reverseOrder(comparator));
    }
```

Comment: No sorry, not working either. (I also tried with the reverse order)

Comment: What is the actual type of `getStateList()` in `Command` class? One presume it is a `List<State>`, or ?

Comment: Yes, it is a `List<Etat>` (State in french) : `private List<Etat> etatList;`

Comment: and the `getEtatList()` method is just a getter, right? It doesn't copy the list? in fact can you paste the code for that method, and also where `etatList` is instiated via `new` ...

Comment: And how are you displaying the commands list in the html page? if it is jsp, or how? Can you show the presentation code also.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected, your problem is somewhere else:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<State> states = Arrays.asList(new State(2015, 1, 1),
                                     new State(2014, 1, 1),
                                     new State(2016, 1, 1));
  System.out.println(states); //not ordered
  states.sort(new Comparator<State>() {
    @Override public int compare(State o1, State o2) {
      return o1.getStateDate().compareTo(o2.getStateDate());
    }
  });
  System.out.println(states); //ordered
}

public static class State {
  private final LocalDate stateDate;
  public State(int year, int month, int day) {
    this.stateDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
  }
  public LocalDate getStateDate() { return stateDate; }
  @Override public String toString() { return stateDate.toString(); }
}
```

Note that you seem to be using Java 8 and your comparator can be written:

```
states.sort(comparing(State::getStateDate));
```

Comment: Can you try with creating a new class called Command, having a list of States as a property ? Then you create a list of commands, and try to order every list of state

Comment: @trichetriche That won't make a difference, if one list can be sorted, several lists can be sorted too (unless you have messed up in the command class and are sharing a list or send a copy or .... - but I can't guess what you have done). You should read the link to MCVE I posted in an earlier comment and follow its recommendations.

Comment: my classes remain untouched since I got them as Entity Classes. And my code is very long, this is why I can't really focus on creating a good example. Maybe if I make a git repository ?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your question, as I have just experienced this.  I implemented 'Comparable' (as I have done many other times) on my JPA Entity class.  When doing a Collections.sort on myMainJPA_Object.getMyList(), the overriden comparable method does not get invoked.

My work-around has been to create a new List as an ArrayList (for example), do a .addAll(myObject.getMyList()), then do Collections.sort on that new list, and then the sort works (my comparable method is invoked on the sort).  For example:

```
List<ObjectsToSort> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
tempList.addAll(jpaEntity.getListOfStuff());
Collections.sort(tempList);
//Then you could set the list again
jpaEntity.setListOfStuff(tempList);
```

I really don't like this solution, but I don't know any other way around it, and haven't found anything about this problem (until your post).  I liked your @OrderBy annotation suggestion, in my case though I need to re-sort again on a different method call, so this solution works for me.