# Sorting list of objects on datetime (cannot resolve method 'compareTo')

Tags: java, sorting, datetime, android-studio

I'm trying to sort an array of objects according to the DateTime of the objects. I've used the following example to create my solution:

[Sort objects in ArrayList by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date)

The method I use looks like this:

```
        List<SomeEvent> myEvents = new ArrayList<>();
//...
//left out the part where the List is filled with Objects
//...
        Collections.sort(myEvents, new Comparator<SomeEvent>() {
            public int compare(SomeEvent se1, SomeEvent se2) {
                return se1.getStartTime().compareTo(se2.getStartTime());
            }
        });
```

I get the error message "Cannot resolve method 'compareTo(com.google.api.client.util.DateTime)'

Any pointers as to what I'm missing?

Edit:
My class SomeEvent now implements Comparable as suggested:

```
public class SomeEvent extends SomeTask implements Comparable<SomeEvent>
{ 
private DateTime startTime; 

private DateTime endTime;


     public DateTime getStartTime() {
         return startTime;
     }

     public DateTime getEndTime() {
         return endTime;
     }

 }
```

Now, however, I get the hint that I need to either declare my class as abstract (which is not possible in the context it is used) or implement the abstract method 'compareTo(T)' in 'Comparable'.

How can I implement the abstract method?

Comment: Your `SomeEvent` class doesn't implmenet comparable interface

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera:  
Ok, thanks for the hint, but if I implement the comparable interface like this: public class SomeEvent extends SomeTask implements Comparable<SomeEvent> { ... } 
I am told that I must either declare the class as abstract (which is not an option) or implement the abstract method 'compareTo(t)' in 'Comparable'. How do I do this?

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera *"Your `SomeEvent` class doesn't implmenet comparable interface"* ... it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this

```
Collections.sort(myEvents, new Comparator<SomeEvent>() {
        public int compare(SomeEvent se1, SomeEvent se2) {
            return (int) (se1.getStartTime().getValue() - se2.getStartTime().getValue());
        }
    });
```

So, I see, you are using not [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), where `compareTo` method exists, but [com.google.api.client.util.DateTime](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.19.0/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime), in which there is no `compareTo` method.

Comment: That is definitely my problem, thank you.
However, now I have to work out some syntax error, it doesn't work like this quite yet.

Comment: @Sorcha, I updated answer, could you please check it?

Comment: The current problem is strange - it tells me "unnecessary semicolon" in the third line (the one after getValue()), but tells me that a semicolon is expecte ("; expected") and "unexpected token" at the same time.
So right now I've fixed it by casting the DateTime to Date and using the original function.