# Null safe date comparator for sorting in Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm using this code to get the newest item. How can I get this to be null safe and sort with null dates last (oldest)?

Note: createDt is a joda LocalDate object.

```
Optional<Item> latestItem = 
     items.stream()
          .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getCreateDt().compareTo(e1.getCreateDt()))
          .findFirst();
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how you'd do it with lambdas but we're using a generic compare method for that, i.e. it might be something like `(e1, e2) -> compareNullable( e2.getCreateDt(), e1.getCreateDt())` in your case (you'd have to provide the `compareNullable(T,T)` method somewhere).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

If it's the `Item`s that may be null, use @rgettman's solution.

If it's the `LocalDate`s that may be null, use this:

```
items.stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::getCreateDt, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder())));
```

In either case, note that `sorted().findFirst()` is likely to be inefficient as most standard implementations sort the entire stream first. You should use [Stream.min](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) instead.

Comment: Is there an alternative to the reverse? it's confusing to me.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach: Sure, that would be `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

Answer (score 27):

You can turn your own null-unsafe `Comparator` into an null-safe one by wrapping it [`Comparator.nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-).  (There is a `Comparator.nullsFirst` also.)

> Returns a null-friendly comparator that considers `null` to be greater than non-null. When both are `null`, they are considered equal.  If both are non-null, the specified `Comparator` is used to determine the order.

```
.sorted(Comparator.nullsLast(
     (e1, e2) -> e2.getCreateDt().compareTo(e1.getCreateDt())))
.findFirst();
```

Comment: Why are you not using `Comparator.comparing`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman While you certainly can use `Comparator.comparing`, I was looking to solve the immediate problem.  Paul's answer is better anyway, so I upvoted it.

Comment: NullPointerException will be thrown, when e2.getCreateDt() == null

Comment: This helps with `e1` or `e2` being null, but not when getCreatedTt() returns null