# Java 8 lambda comparator with null value check

Tags: lambda, java-8

I've implemented a sorting on a collection using a lambda expression for the comparison. I have to check for null values, so I came up with this solution for the comparator

```
(a,b)->(
    (a.getStartDate() == null) 
        ? ( (b.getStartDate() == null) ? 0 : -1)
        : ( (b.getStartDate() == null)?1:a.getStartDate().compareTo(b.getStartDate()) )
);
```

I've already checked some questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401606/comparator-with-null-values), but they all refer to pre-lambda code.

Do java lambda expressions give me the chance to avoid the two 'if' statements? Can I perform the task in a cleaner way?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361156/null-safe-date-comparator-for-sorting-in-java-8-stream and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518961/comparator-based-on-different-nullable-fields-of-an-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350996/java-8-comparator-nullsfirst-naturalorder-confused

Comment: Thank you @Tunaki !! deleting the question - edit: can't do this because it is answered...

Answer (score 211, accepted):

There are default implementations within [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) you can use: `nullsFirst` or `nullsLast`:

```
Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getStartDate, 
  Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())
)
```