# how can i get last 7 days from current day in ascending order in java?

Tags: java, date

I am using following code to get the last 7 days:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime();
String[] days = new String[6];
days[0] = sdf.format(date);

for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    date = cal.getTime();
    days[i] = sdf.format(date);
}

for(String x: days){
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

And this is giving the following output:

```
2016-04-14
2016-04-13
2016-04-12
2016-04-11
2016-04-10
2016-04-09
```

But I want this instead:

```
2016-04-09
2016-04-10
2016-04-11
2016-04-12
2016-04-13
2016-04-14
```

If I use the following line below the code it will give me the correct order:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(days);
Collections.reverse(list);
days = (String[]) list.toArray();

for(String x: days){
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

But is there any other way to get the last 7 days in ascending order in one shot?

Comment: How about you start by subtracting 7 days and then add one each time in your loop?

Comment: use http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ when you have to work with time/dates!!

Answer (score 14):

I would simplify your method a bit, if you want this output you don't need to create an `String[]` array, either loop twice, you can achieve same with a single `for-loop`, one `Calendar` and the `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// get starting date
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -6);

// loop adding one day in each iteration
for(int i = 0; i< 6; i++){
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2016-04-09 
2016-04-10 
2016-04-11 
2016-04-12 
2016-04-13 
2016-04-14
```

[Working IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/HezrTe)

Answer (score 6):

Using java8 and joda you can write something like:

```
LocalDate weekBeforeToday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(7);
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 7)
    .mapToObj(weekBeforeToday::plusDays)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It prints:

```
2016-04-08
2016-04-09
2016-04-10
2016-04-11
2016-04-12
2016-04-13
2016-04-14
```

If you need collection you have to use collector.

In your example you're printing 6 days so I don't now if it's your mistake or you need 6 days instead of 7.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion:

```
String[] days = new String[6];

for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  days[i] = LocalDate.now().minusDays(days.length - i - 1).toString();
}

for (String x : days) {
  System.out.println(x);
}
```

And possibly even clearer, using a list:

```
List<String> days = new ArrayList<> ();
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

for (LocalDate d = now.minusDays(5); !d.isAfter(now); d = d.plusDays(1)) {
  days.add(d.toString());
}

for (String x : days) {
  System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop the other way:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date=cal.getTime();
    String[] days = new String[6];
    days[0]=sdf.format(date);

    for(int i = 1; i< 6; i++){
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-1);
           date=cal.getTime();
           days[i]=sdf.format(date);
    }

    for(int i = (days.length-1); i >= 0; i--){
        System.out.println(days[i]);
    }
```

This is the output:

```
2016-04-09 
2016-04-10 
2016-04-11 
2016-04-12 
2016-04-13 
2016-04-14
```

Answer (score 1):

## `Collections.sort`

You can use [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) method. It's a static method. You pass it the list and a comparator. It uses a modified mergesort algorithm over the list. That's why you must pass it a comparator to do the pair comparisons. This has been answered before as well.

[Sort objects in ArrayList by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers use old outmoded classes or are overly complicated.

## java.time

The old date-time classes have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later, with back-ports to Java 6 & 7 and to Android. The old classes have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

### `LocalDate`

Among the new classes is `LocalDate` to represent a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. While not stored, a time zone is required to determine “today”. A new dawns earlier in the east, so the date can vary between time zones, “tomorrow” in Paris while “yesterday” in Montréal.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

You can add and subtract. We want to go back a week, so subtract a week.

```
LocalDate limit = today.minusWeeks( 1 );
```

Loop a day at a time until we reach the limit. Collect each date as we increment.

A [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an ordered collection, a sequence. The [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class is an appropriate implementation for our needs.

```
List< LocalDate > list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Loop while each decremented date is still later than our stopping point (a week ago).

```
LocalDate localDate = today;
while ( localDate.isAfter( limit ) ) {
    list.add( localDate );
    // Setup next loop.
    localDate = localDate.minusDays( 1 );
}
```

## Sort

Lastly, sort your list in either direction you desire.

The [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class (note the plural 's' in name) provides many utility methods. Call [`sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) for natural order. Call [`reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-) for the opposite of natural order.

```
Collections.sort( list );
Collections.reverse( list );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cents, using Streams:

```java
LocalDate start = LocalDate.now().minusDays(6);
Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
    .limit(7)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Here's a working example](https://ideone.com/8SvPtX).

As Ole V.V. mentioned in the comments, since Java 9, they've added a convenience method to get a stream of dates: [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-).

It then would look like something like this:

```java
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
now.minusDays(6).datesUntil(now.plusDays(1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Because you want the end date to be today, we need to provide `now.plusDays(1)` as argument to `datesUntil`. That is because the given date is exclusive.

Comment: @OleVV I forgot about that, good call. I'll include that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Change `days`to an array of `Date` and then convert it to list and sort the list with `Collections.sort(list);`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date=cal.getTime();
    Date[] days = new Date[6];
    days[0]= date;

    for(int i = 1; i< 6; i++){
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-1);
           date=cal.getTime();
           days[i]=date;
    }

    List<Date> list = Arrays.asList(days);
    Collections.sort(list);

    for(Date x: days){
        System.out.println(sdf.format(x));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop going forward, you can try to use a loop going backwards. Replace the following two lines of your code:

```
days[0] = sdf.format(date);

for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
```

with:

```
days[days.length - 1] = sdf.format(date);

for(int i = days.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
```

OUTPUT:

```
2016-04-14
2016-04-13
2016-04-12
2016-04-11
2016-04-10
2016-04-09
```

---

EDIT: Better yet, use [Jordi Castilla's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36621252/1682559).

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers of days is constant you can simply start filling the array from the end (Of course after allocating the table: `new String[DAYS]`):

```
private static final DAYS = 6;
//...
for(int i = DAYS; i >= 0; i--){
     cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-1);
     date = cal.getTime();
     days[i] = sdf.format(date);
}
```