# I have an array of objects and each object has been assigned a date, how can I sort these objects in order of date?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, datetime, bubble-sort

I currently have an array containing objects called 'People'. Each one has a name, day, month, year (of birth). I want to convert these to dates and use the .isAfter() method to compare them and resort them but it does not sort them by date at all. Here is a simpler version of the code

```
    for (int i = 0; i<peopleArray.size()-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<peopleArray.size()-1; j++)
        {

            LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(i).getDOBYear()), 
                                      Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(i).getDOBMonth()), 
                                      Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(i).getDOBDay()));


            LocalDate secondDate= LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(j).getDOBYear()), 
                  Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(j).getDOBMonth()), 
                  Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(j).getDOBDay()));

            if(firstDate.isAfter(secondDate)) 
            {
                Person temp = peopleArray[i];
                peopleArray[i] = peopleArray[i+1];
                peopleArray[i+1] = temp;
             }              
        }
    }
```

'Person' is the name of the object. Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Write a Comparable implementation and pass that to the Collections.sort method.

Comment: This post may help clarify what @duffymo means http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking for a simpler solution in java, then solution by `user2004685` should do.

Since you've tagged `bubble-sort`, I'm guessing you need help with the issue in your code.

**Issues:**

1. The loops will **never cover the last element in the list**. It should run till `i/j < size()`.
2. The **Swap block swaps different elements than the compared elements**. You're comparing elements at `i` and `j` location but swapping `i` and `i+1`
3. I'm assuming the swap code which access the Array using subscript operator is working on another variable and not the list variable (*As Subscript is not applicable for list*).
4. You can enhance the loop by reducing the loop duration. Refer to bubble-sort code provided [here](http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/) for reference.

**Code with Correction:**

```
for (int i = 0; i<peopleArray.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<peopleArray.size(); j++)
    {
        LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(i).getDOBYear()), 
                                  Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(i).getDOBMonth()), 
                                  Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(i).getDOBDay()));

        LocalDate secondDate= LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(j).getDOBYear()), 
              Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(j).getDOBMonth()), 
              Integer.parseInt(peopleArray.get(j).getDOBDay()));

        if(firstDate.isAfter(secondDate)) 
        {
            Person temp = peopleArray[i];
            peopleArray[i] = peopleArray[j];
            peopleArray[j] = temp;
         }              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As user2004685 and duffymo said, you need to write a custom `compareTo`, and the example user2004685 looks correct to me (I don't have a compiler on this computer at the moment).

One addendum I would suggest, is that you might not want a `People` class - maybe you just want the array you have now, and you don't always want to sort instances of `Person` in the way you describe. If so, the thing to do is pass a `Comparator` to `Arrays.sort()`:

```
Arrays.sort(people, new Comparator<Person>() {
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        // implement Person.getDOB() in the appropriate way
        return p1.getDOB().compareTo(p2.getDOB());
    }});
```

Or, if you're using Java8, you can do this even more succinctly with a lambda:

```
Arrays.sort(people, (p1,p2) -> p1.getDOB().compareTo(p2.getDOB()));
```

Answer (score 0):

As `duffymo` suggested, you just have to implement the `Comparable` interface on `People` class as follows:

```
public class People implements Comparable<People> {

    /* Members */
    private String name;
    private int dobDay;
    private int dobMonth;
    private int dobYear;

    /* Getter, Setter, Constructor */

    /* Get Date Function */
    private Date getDate() {
        return LocalDate.of(this.dobYear, this.dobMonth, this.dobDay);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(People people) {
        return this.getDate().isAfter(people.getDate());
    }
}
```

And then finally sort the Array as follows:

```
Collections.sort(peopleArray);
```