# How to change sequence of list View items in android

Tags: android, json, listview, calendar, listviewitem

I have a calendar like this:

[materialise calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eO9Y.png)

every tic icon shows their corresponding event.

and I have a json response like this:

```
{
    "Table": [
        {
            "userid": 4,
            "eventname": "adi",
            "eventdate": "/Date(1484121600000-0800)/",
            "eventcolor": "2413AD",
            "autoid": 2005
        },
        {
            "userid": 4,
            "eventname": "Aditya",
            "eventdate": "/Date(1479974400000-0800)/",
            "eventcolor": "5986FF",
            "autoid": 1011
        },
        {
            "userid": 4,
            "eventname": "aditya",
            "eventdate": "/Date(1484812800000-0800)/",
            "eventcolor": "13AD1A",
            "autoid": 2006
        },
        {
            "userid": 4,
            "eventname": "dfgdgdgs",
            "eventdate": "/Date(1478678400000-0800)/",
            "eventcolor": "AD3D1F",
            "autoid": 1005
        },
        {
            "userid": 4,
            "eventname": "dfgdgdgs",
            "eventdate": "/Date(1478678400000-0800)/",
            "eventcolor": "AD3D1F",
            "autoid": 1006
        }
    ]
}
```

Here comes the real problem.When I click any date on the calendar, above json response comes in a listView according to sequence of json. But, I want to change the sequence according to which date i clicked(i.e. Date i  am clicked in the calendar, that date comes first in the list and remaining item comes after that).

I'm not posting any code, If any one wants to see my code, please ask.

Comment: You can sort your list according to your preferences!

Comment: How ,Can U gave me a sample

Comment: @ Morphez: Check if it can help -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/5927408/4018207

Comment: Ok ,let me try @AndiGeeky

Answer (score 0):

When you parse the list from JSON at that time you check the date of each object and compare to the clicked date and store that particular index. 
Then you simply parse the list from JSON response
at parsing time you remove that particular object at that stored index and move to the first position of that list.
**Use code like:**

```
list.removeAt(stored_index);
list.add(0, objectOfList);
```

> and then simply add that list to adapter

Comment: Can U please explain something more@Vijay.  i.e. what is stored_index and objectOfList.

Comment: stored_index is the position of the object in response list who has the date equals to your date was clicked.
And objectOfList is the object of the list at the position of stored_index.