# Sort an arrayList based on time using collections

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am having times in different time formats stored in my arrayList
they are

```
Tue, 05 Sep 2017 09:25:05 +0100                               
Tue, 05 Sep 2017 01:28:06 -0700           
Thu, 31 Aug 2017 17:51:58 GMT                    
Tue, 05 Sep 2017 08:31:18 GMT                          
04 Sep 2017 21:34:51                 
Tue, 05 Sep 2017 03:28:17 -0400
```

now I want to convert different time format in a single format and sort the list based on time using collections.sort

```
List<NewsModel> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And My object Class `NewsModel` is like this

```
public class NewsModel {

    String headlines;
    String weblink;
    String imagelink;




    public String getHeadlines() {
        return headlines;
    }

    public void setHeadlines(String headlines) {
        this.headlines = headlines;
    }

    public String getWeblink() {
        return weblink;
    }

    public void setWeblink(String weblink) {
        this.weblink = weblink;
    }

    public String getImagelink() {
        return imagelink;
    }

    public void setImagelink(String imagelink) {
        this.imagelink = imagelink;
    }

    public String getShortnews() {
        return shortnews;
    }

    public void setShortnews(String shortnews) {
        this.shortnews = shortnews;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    String shortnews;
    String source;
    String date;
}
```

Comment: show us the code... what is the type of the List?

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date

Comment: please take a look on code  above and help me

Comment: Hello  Bapusaheb Shinde sir  i have time in different formats and i have store d it in String type can u please guide

Comment: is the date attribute is part of object class ?

Comment: just convert your date to Milli seconds and then sort

Comment: @AshutoshDwivedi, what if you DON't store the time in different formats, and use actual `ZonedDateTime` (or `Calendar`) objects instead?

Comment: these formats are for uk....so if u can help using actualDateTime it will be a great help @M.Prokhorov