# How to sort date Firestore in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to list out the newest order until the oldest order. I have set the date format before the users do payments.

```
// Get current date & time
val currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
// Format date time style
currentDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM))
// Finalize convert format
val date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm").format(currentDateTime)
```

After the users do the payment, it will add to my Firestore. When I retrieve the data, it's only descending my date of the month.

```
    fun getOrderList(activity: Fragment, recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        mFirestore.collection(Constants.ORDERS)
            .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->

                val orderItem = result.toObjects(UserOrderList::class.java)
                recyclerView.adapter = OrderListItemAdapter(activity, activity.requireContext(), orderItem)
            }
    }
```

[Firestore data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gADZ.png)

My date output like
06 Jun 2021, 10:50 -> 05 Nov 2021, 14:22 -> 03 May 2021, 10:58 -> 03 Apr 2021, 09:13

[Date image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVb7P.jpg)

How can I get sort the date from newest until oldest and list it out into my RecyclerView?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: **Possible duplicate** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date

Comment: @AlexMamo I have been upload my database structure. What should I edit my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting the desired results because the `date` field inside the document is a String, and when you order strings, the order is [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

To solve this, you have to change the type of the field to be a [Firestore Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027), and then your query will work as expected.

Comment: Is it still available time format if I use timestamp?

Comment: Yes, it is. A [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) object contains a time component with nanosecond precision.

Comment: Can you teach me how to write? I'm still new not so familiar and don't understand how to code date format.

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: I tried to set DateTimeFormatter in my adapter, but it doesn't works and get the Required: TemporalAccessor.

val date = item.date!!.toDate()
val formattedDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm").format(date)

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: But remember, you should use a Timestamp object as explained in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/how-to-add-a-timestamp-in-firestore-with-android/48475027#48475027).

Answer (score 0):

I would add one more field in the Firestore, which accepts [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds. Let's call `order_created_date`. Then while retrieving the list of the Orders, you can use the same `orderBy("order_created_date",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)` method. In that case it will compare numbers.

I would also suggest using this approach of getting current time

```
val currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
currentDateTime.timeInMillis
```

As your method `LocalDateTime.now()` requires API level 26 or above.

Regards.

Comment: Is it available to format date? I'm still new not familiar in date

Comment: Yes you can format Unix time into any Date format you want. Also, I agree what @Alex explained. His approach is almost the same as this one. The comparison should not be with Strings)